# Need to add links to a gallery

Tags: html, css

Was doing a tutorial for an image gallery and got it just the way I wanted it but it doesn't work when I try to add links. Any ideas what to try?

http://codepen.io/cwilliams23/pen/oFzAb?editors=110

This is the code for each thumbnail and image, the first link is for the thumbnail and 
the second is for the main picture:

```
<input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4"/>
<label for="id4">
    <img src="image/url/link" width="100"/>Up
</label>
<img src="image/url/link"/>
```

Comment: your codepen appears to be working fine for me (all images are loading).. what isnt working for you?

Comment: What isn't working? What have you tried? Please read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question.

Comment: It works perfectly til I try to throw a link onto a picture then it goes crazy on it. I'll add a link and update my code for a view.

Answer (score 0):

To add a link to your pictures you need to add the following code. `<a href="http://www.whateveryourlinkisgoeshere.com";>Up</a>`

```
<input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4"/>
<label for="id4">
    <a href="http://www.whateveryourlinkisgoeshere.com";><img src="image/url/link" width="100"/>Up</a>
</label>
<img src="image/url/link"/>
```